# Right configuration for spring mvc app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I read this  "It is a best practice to keep a clear separation between middle-tier services such as business logic components and data access classes (that are typically defined in the ApplicationContext) and web- related components such as controllers and view resolvers (that are defined in the WebApplicationContext per Dispatcher Servlet)."

And decide configure my application like that 4 separate xml file

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="appname">
         <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

dao.xml

```
<!-- MySQL JDBC Data Source-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>        
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://#{mysqlDbCredentials.hostname}:#{mysqlDbCredentials.port}/#{mysqlDbCredentials.name}"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{mysqlDbCredentials.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{mysqlDbCredentials.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JpaPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>               
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.showSql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>        
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="appname" use-default-filters="false">
         <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

web.xml(load spring context)

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
            <param-value> 
              /WEB-INF/spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Load spring beans definition files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/dao.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

But I'm absolutly confused. 
1)I don't understand how many context in this case I get.
2)I want easy replace tx mode on aspectj (which work just in ome context as I know). But when I replace I get error with transation.

Main problem that I want to have universal variant for both type of transaction
Here I add `mode="aspectj"` and I have annotation like @Service, @Resourse, on concrete classes

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

All seems should work but I get next exception on `flush`

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1239)
at [internal classes]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Please, help me uderstand better

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using XML? I find that modularizing configuration is a lot simpler using JavaConfig.

Comment: @chrylis Just a habbit and need to make it quickly

Comment: How many contexts you get depends on how all of these files are getting loaded. I don't see anything that imports anything else; how is Spring finding all of these? For what it's worth, I regularly build apps as several-module Maven projects, and I include appropriate `@Configuration` classes and just component-scan them all from a single entry point, most lately Spring Boot, but a traditional XML file like your first one would also work.

Comment: @chrylis I added web.xml where load spring files

Comment: There's not enough information to tell for sure; I'm unclear about where the AspectJ line is, and you haven't posted your class. It's possible that this is a self-call issue if Spring is using proxy AOP instead of AspectJ.

Answer (score 3):

convention is you have one root context, normally applicationContext.xml. Then different servlet contexts (for different modules/functionality)... myapp-servlet.xml.

The servlet context can see everything in root context, but not the other way. Controllers and webby stuff(static resources) go in servlet context, everything else (eg service, and security) go in root context.

You can import different files as you please. But define those two contexts in your web.xml (or Java conf equivalent).

I still do it the old fashioned xml way, you don't *have* to use java conf.

Whats your actual error ?

Comment: I added detailed description my problem. Please, read updated variant

Comment: Did you actually annotate the service classes with @Transactional ?

Comment: Yes, `@Service @Transactional public class MyServiceImpl`